# How can I create a database diagram, showing clearly the FK and PK in SQL Studio 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-diagrams

I would like to know the best way to create a database structure diagram, that shows relationships between certain tables. I am using SSMS 2016.

I tried using "database diagram" option in the SSMS but it doesnt clearly show the FK and the PK in the tables.

Is there any other way to achieve this easily?
I do not need all the tables, just some selected ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't clearly show?" Because it definitely does show the FK relationships at a minimum, assuming they've been properly defined in the database schema.

Comment: Hey alroc, it only shows the name of the FK between the two tables, unless you move the cursor over it.

Comment: Can you describe what it is that you want, instead of describing what it does that you don’t like? “Show clearly” is a somewhat subjective measure.

Comment: I cant add a screenshot here I guess, that would have helped. What I need is a database diagram that shows the FK and the PK associated with the tables, thats all.